# Need to cancel an actionscript command stop() and continue my project

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an Actionscript on an invisible button in my Flash project and it is supposed to stop on a frame if it is clicked. This is the script on the button:

```
invisobutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopframe);
function stopframe(Event:MouseEvent):void{
stop();
}
```

with invisobutton being the instance name of the button. It works if you click anywhere inside the invisible button the movie stops on that frame. My problem is that I do not know how to cancel the stop and continue where the movie paused. Is there a counter for the `stop()` command so that it can be like off and there was an on switch? I thought about using a second function for go to and play like this:

```
invisobutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, restart);
                              function restart(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay(*);
```

but I am not sure how to know  what to put into the (*) so that it plays from right where it was stopped.

If someone could please advise me if there is a reverse command to `stop()` that can turn it off ans start again. I already tried `play()` but I got errors from Flash over it. I thought about `start()` but I had never heard of or seen such a command. Or if someone could tell me a way to correctly retrieve the frame number when the `stop()` command executes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that what you want is to use the same button to toggle between play and stop, you can use the following code:

```
var lastFrame:int;
var isPlaying:Boolean = true;

invisobutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleFrame);

function toggleFrame(Event:MouseEvent):void { 
    if ( isPlaying ) {
        lastFrame = this.currentFrame;
        stop();         
    } else {
        this.gotoAndPlay( lastFrame );
    }

    isPlaying = ! isPlaying;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I figured it out myself and it is up and running. But again, thanks for the reply!!

Comment: @user581457: You might as well accept the answer as correct and close the question.

Comment: I would love to but your script does not do anything at all when I click  on the button!! The movie just keeps playing as if there was nothing done at all.

Comment: Perhaps I am simply not using your script correctly because it is not having any effect whatsoever for me. This is the initial script I had which did nothing but stop the movie completely, leaving no option to continue watching:

Comment: Here is the script as I am using it:

Comment: import flash.events.MouseEvent;
invisobutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopframe);
function stopframe(event:Event):void{
         stop();}

Comment: Here is the script with yours added in that is doing nothing:

Comment: import flash.events.MouseEvent;
invisobutton.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, stopLastFrame);

function stopLastFrame(event:Event):void{
    if(this.currentFrame == this.totalFrames){
        if(counter >= 3){
            stop();
            setTimeout(startAgain,3000);
        }else{
            counter++;
        }
    }    
}function startAgain():void{
    play();
}

Comment: But when I change it to your script it does not seem to have any effect when you click on the invisible button on the stage. It just does nothing. Can you explain why please??

Comment: I don't know how you have set up your fla. You just provided a line of code and wanted to improve it. If the initial code you posted was working, the one I submitted was build ontop of that, just adding a bit of logic to do what you wanted.